# What to be mindful of with cake flour

Tags: baking, cake, pancakes

I substituted cake flour for AP FLOUR in my pancake recipe. Do I need to reduce the liquid ingredients as compared to AP flour? My batter seemed runnier and therefore pancakes were flatter—but also seemed more tender. Anything else to be aware of when working with cake flour? Should I cook at a lower heat? Since cake four produces less stiffness (gluten) do I need an additional levener like baking soda and an acid?

1 cup AP flour
1 tbsp sugar
1 tsp baking powder
1 tsp kosher salt
1 tsp vanilla extract
1 beaten egg
3 tbsp melted butter
.75 cup milk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake flour is mainly used in situations where less gluten is desired, that's why the pancake was more tender.  Cake flour is also lighter in color and texture, since it is usually bleached.  It is also milled finer.  If you are substituting cake for AP flour, you will probably need a couple of additional tablespoons of cake flour per cup of AP flour.  Leave your leavening as is.